# What is the advantage of Properties Triggers over Data Triggers in WPF

Tags: wpf, triggers

I try to understand the advantage of Properties Triggers over Data Triggers in WPF.
It seems that Properties Triggers can be triggered only by a value that changed in dependency property, and Data Triggers can be triggered both by a value that changed in dependency property, and a value that changed in a .Net object that implement INotifyPropertyChange. So my question is, why not always use Data Triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trigger` looks at properties in the item you're styling/templating, whereas `DataTrigger` looks at the current `DataContext` by default.

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <!-- applied when mouse is over the ListBoxItem -->
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Kent">
            <!-- applied when the ListBoxItem's data has a Name property set to "Kent" -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: So the only property trigger advantage is, that it's a shorter way to get triggered by a value change in the styled item property? since I can bind to the styled item properties using DataTrigger...

Comment: I highly suspect it's more efficient, too.